# Why vue transition component is no working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im triying to show models with transition effect

```
<template>
<transition name="modal">
    <v-tour v-if="tourType === 'normal'"
        name="myTour"
        :steps="steps"
    />
    <v-tour
        v-else-if="tourType === 'tip'"
        type="tip"
        name="myTour"
        :sticky="true"
    />
    <v-tour 
        v-else
        :type="tourType"
        name="myTour"
    ></v-tour>
</transition>
```

Here is the style

```
.modal-enter {
 opacity: 0;
 }
.modal-leave-active {
 opacity: 0;
}
.modal-enter .modal-container,
.modal-leave-active .modal-container {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  transform: scale(1.25);
 }
```

Modals are showing but without transition effect, i tried with `mode="out-in"` but did not work, what should i do?

Comment: what is the `transition effect` - you have no CSS transition defined

Comment: @JaromandaX https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html

Comment: I said a ***CSS transition***, I can see you have a `<transition>` element, because I can read - that's why asked what transition ***effect*** you were expecting without having any ***CSS transition*** defined - sorry if my abbreviated sentence confused - I'll expand my sentences. *As you have no **transition** property in your CSS, what `transition effect` were you expecting?*

Answer (score 1):

You must add css transition property and css properties you change:

[image: vue docs]

i`ll think this must works:

```
.modal-enter .modal-container,
.modal-leave-active .modal-container {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  transform: scale(1.25);
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
```

or

```
...
transition: transform 0.5s ease;
...
```

if you want to animated all changed props, you need to add *all* in your transition prop:

```
transition: all 0.3s ease;
```